# Проблема плавного изменения положения DIV с помощью JS

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть слой:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px;" onClick="isMove(this)">Лол</div>
```

Есть скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function isMove(element) {
   for(t=0;t<10;t++){
      setTimeout('actMove('+element+')', t*100);
   }
}
function actMove(element) {
   element.style.left=parseInt(element.style.left)+1+'px';
   element.style.top=parseInt(element.style.top)+1+'px';
}
</script>
```

Поидее всё должно работать, *this* передаётся нормально в первую ф-ию, но вторая не запускается.

P.S. если поменять

```
setTimeout('actMove('+element+')', t*100);
```

на

```
actMove(element);
```

то всё работает, но разумеется положение меняется мгновенно. Как можно исправить?

Comment: могу предположить вариант:

    setTimeout(function(){actMove(element);}, t*100);//добавить функцию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не правильно вызвали функцию в сетинтервал, нужно так

```
function isMove(element) {
    for(t=0;t<10;t++){
        setTimeout(function() {
            actMove(element)
        }, t*100);
    }
}
function actMove(element) {
    element.style.left=parseInt(element.style.left)+1+'px';
    element.style.top=parseInt(element.style.top)+1+'px';
}
```

А лучше делать так:

```
function animate(obj) {
var start = new Date();
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    var progress = (new Date() - start ) / obj.duration;
    if(progress > 1) progress = 1;
    obg.step(progress);
    if(progress == 1) clearInterval(timer);
}, obj.delay)
```

}

```
var obj = {
duration : 1000,
delay : 10,
step : function(progress) {
    elem.style.marginTop = 150 * progress + 'px';
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="myId" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px;" onClick="isMove(this.id)">Лол</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function isMove(elementId) {
   for(t=0;t<10;t++){
      setTimeout('actMove("'+elementId+'")', t*100);
   }
}
function actMove(elementId) {
   var el = document.getElementById(elementId);
   el.style.left=parseInt(el.style.left)+1+'px';
   el.style.top=parseInt(el.style.top)+1+'px';
}
</script>
```

"Почему ID" - потому что вы пытаетесь выполнить по таймауту что-то вроде "`actMove(HTMLDivElement)`" (див преобразовывается в строку). Нужно либо использовать ID, либо делать element глобальной переменной перед таймаутом и тд (это совсем ересь).